# Get-ADComputer from Multiple Computers from a CSVFile

Tags: powershell, csv, format

I have a csv file full of computer information formatted:

```
Name    OS  Site Code    AD_Status  Region  Tech
computerone Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
computertwo Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
computerthree   Windows 10 Enterprise   ****    Exists  Chicago T T
```

I'm running a Powershell script that grabs the computer name from the csv file and checks its 'modifyTimeStamp' field.

```
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\****\testexcel.csv'-Delimiter ","
$numofcompsincsv = $csvfile.psobject.properties.value[0] - 1

for ($i = 0; $i -le $numofcompsincsv; $i++) {
    Get-ADComputer -identity $csvfile[$i].psobject.properties.value[0] -Properties * | FT Name, modifyTimeStamp 
}
```

The problem with this is that it prints the computer information one by one, for example:

```
Name            modifyTimeStamp
----            ---------------
computerone 7/19/2019 11:06:22 AM

Name            modifyTimeStamp
----            ---------------
computertwo 7/24/2019 6:02:14 AM

Name            modifyTimeStamp
----            ---------------
computerthree 7/24/2019 2:02:14 AM
```

How can I modify this so that it prints all in one like:

```
Name            modifyTimeStamp
----            ---------------
computerone 7/19/2019 11:06:22 AM
computertwo 7/24/2019 6:02:14 AM
computerthree 7/24/2019 2:02:14 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this with a `for` loop; use the pipe instead:

```
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\****\testexcel.csv' | Select -expand Name | Get-ADComputer -prop modifyTimeStamp | Select Name,ModifyTimeStamp
```

*ETA: I apparently didn't create the CSV (hand-coded) I used for testing quite properly, and had originally piped the CSV to `| Select Name |` instead of expanding the property (which worked in my test). When I re-did it using Excel, I verified that `| Select -expand Name |` was required, per the comment by @js2010.*

Comment: This gives me an error:Get-ADComputer : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline 
input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\***.pstchar:95
+ ... cel.csv' | Select Name | Get-ADComputer -prop modifyTimeStamp | Selec ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Name=computerone}:PSObject) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException

Comment: `| Select -expand Name |`